# Conditional Formatting multiple values by several different string lengths

Tags: excel, excel-formula, heatmap, conditional-formatting, string-length

I wanted to use Conditional Formatting to create a heat map, but include text values in my cells and not just numbers.

So I have about 63 unique combinations of six values, in six different sizes. String lengths for these combinations are 2, 6, 10, 14, 18 and 22. I want six different colors for each string length regardless of what characters they are.
I think I have to create six separate CF rules to apply to the heat map, using =LEN I think - but can't seem to work it out past there.

Answer (score 0):

Strange request, so I may have misunderstood, but *I have to create six separate CF rules to apply to the heat map, using =LEN* seems about right.

Select the range to apply the formatting to, top left to bottom right, in the example I chose C3 to E8:

[image: SO29204020 first example]

HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=LEN(C3)=22
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select your choice of formatting (mine was red), OK, OK.

The repeat much the same for the other five conditions and colours:

[image: SO29204020 second example]

An empty cell or one containing five characters will not take on the conditional formatting:

[image: SO29204020 third example]